# Display Custom Variable by Page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display a specific posts custom variable data to specific pages.

I have the following code

```
<?php
if ( is_page( '24' ) ) {
    // This is Podcast
    echo get_post_meta(570, "Youtube Video", true);
    } else if ( is_page ('25') ){
    // This is Video
    echo get_post_meta(568, "Youtube Video", true);
} else if ( is_front_page () ){
    // This is the Home Page
    echo get_post_meta(550, "Youtube Video", true);
} else {
    //Other Pages
    echo '<h1>APPLIES TO ALL INSIDE PAGES</h1>';
}
?>
```

This results in the home page working as expected with the "is_front_page" conditional, but the other declared pages get the 'else' applied to them.  It's as though the page conditional is not hooked.  Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

These items were categories, not pages.  Confirmed by checking the wordpress menu to discover what the objects were.

The code below operates as intended.

```
<?php
if ( is_category( 'podcast' ) ) {
    // Display Podcast Specific Content
    echo get_post_meta(570, "Youtube Video", true);
    } else if ( is_category ('video') ){
    // This is Video
    echo get_post_meta(568, "Youtube Video", true);
} else if ( is_front_page () ){
    // This is the Home Page
    echo get_post_meta(550, "Youtube Video", true);
} else {
    //Other Pages (Display Home Page Video)
    echo get_post_meta(570, "Youtube Video", true);
}?>
```